# Mysql: 1062: Duplicate entry '' for key 'reg_no'

Tags: php, mysql

Hi in this code it showing error:

> ["1062: Duplicate entry '' for key 'reg_no'"]

Can any one please help me. Why is it showing this error duplicate entry when adding the field with name `reg_no`.

I want to return true if query executes.

**php**

```
<?php

mysql_connect("localhost","root",""); 
mysql_select_db("hms");
//$student_name = !empty($_POST['student_name']) ? $_POST['student_name'] : $_GET['student_name'];
//$roll_no = !empty($_POST['roll_no']) ? $_POST['roll_no'] : $_GET['roll_no'];
$relation=!empty($_POST['relation']) ? $_POST['relation'] : $_GET['relation'];
    $initial_id=!empty($_POST['initial_id']) ? $_POST['initial_id'] : $_GET['initial_id'];
    $reg_no=!empty($_POST['reg_no']) ? $_POST['reg_no'] : $_GET['reg_no'];
    $pmc=!empty($_POST['pmc']) ? $_POST['pmc'] : $_GET['pmc'];
    $pc=!empty($_POST['pc']) ? $_POST['pc'] : $_GET['pc'];
    $dob=!empty($_POST['dob']) ? $_POST['dob'] : $_GET['dob'];
    $first_name=!empty($_POST['first_name']) ? $_POST['first_name'] : $_GET['first_name'];
    $middle_name=!empty($_POST['middle_name']) ? $_POST['middle_name'] : $_GET['middle_name'];
    $last_name=!empty($_POST['last_name']) ? $_POST['last_name'] : $_GET['last_name'];
    $gender=!empty($_POST['gender']) ? $_POST['gender'] : $_GET['gender'];
    $age=!empty($_POST['student_name']) ? $_POST['student_name'] : $_GET['student_name'];
    $fh=!empty($_POST['fh']) ? $_POST['fh'] : $_GET['fh'];
    $photo=!empty($_POST['photo']) ? $_POST['photo'] : $_GET['photo'];
    $religion_id=!empty($_POST['religion_id']) ? $_POST['religion_id'] : $_GET['religion_id'];
    $caste_id=!empty($_POST['caste_id']) ? $_POST['caste_id'] : $_GET['caste_id'];
    $address=!empty($_POST['address']) ? $_POST['address'] : $_GET['address'];
    $phone_office=!empty($_POST['phone_office']) ? $_POST['phone_office'] : $_GET['phone_office'];
    $pin=!empty($_POST['pin']) ? $_POST['pin'] : $_GET['pin'];
    $phone_resi=!empty($_POST['phone_resi']) ? $_POST['phone_resi'] : $_GET['phone_resi'];
    $email=!empty($_POST['email']) ? $_POST['email'] : $_GET['email'];
    $mobile_no=!empty($_POST['mobile_no']) ? $_POST['mobile_no'] : $_GET['mobile_no'];
    $pmode=!empty($_POST['pmode']) ? $_POST['pmode'] : $_GET['pmode'];
    $id_proof=!empty($_POST['id_proof']) ? $_POST['id_proof'] : $_GET['id_proof'];
    $name_of_kin=!empty($_POST['name_of_kin']) ? $_POST['name_of_kin'] : $_GET['name_of_kin'];
    $blood_group=!empty($_POST['blood_group']) ? $_POST['blood_group'] : $_GET['blood_group'];

$query="INSERT INTO patient_registration(reg_no,patient_main_type_id,   patient_type_id,initial_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,fth_mth_name,religion_id,date_of_birth,caste_id,address,pin,email,id_proof,phone_office,    phone_residence,mobile_no,name_of_kin,relationship,entry_date,entry_time,patient_photo,payment_mode)
                VALUES('$reg_no','$pmc','$pc','$initial_id','$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$fh','$religion_id','$dob','$caste_id','$address','$pin','$email','$id_proof','$phone_office','$phone_resi','$mobile_no','$name_of_kin','','','$relation','$photo','$pmode')";

$json_output = array();
if (!mysql_query($query )) {
  $json_output[] = mysql_errno() . ": ".mysql_error();
}else{
  $json_output[] = true;
}

print(json_encode($json_output));
mysql_close();
?>
```

Comment: Don't add two rows with the same primary key. BTW, your query is wide open to SQL injections.

Comment: I want reg_no as unique why should i delete that one

Answer (score 0):

May be you used reg_no as primary key or unique in that case if you try to add already existing record(registration number) it shows that error.

Comment: Then give the reg_no your trying to insert and 
check the query SELECT reg_no,COUNT(reg_no) FROM patient_registration WHERE reg_no='your_reg_no' and post output.

Comment: So the record is there na...!

Comment: if i want to search with PAT3 means there is no record so i want to write insert query only

Comment: Yes, Hey I gotta doubt, you getting error but is the record inserting into db? If yes simple change $result=mysql_query($query);if(!$result){..}

Comment: print $query and copy paste in phpmyadmin you may find clear error and try to solve it.
Or do
mysql_query("SELECT COUNT(reg_no) table_name where  reg_no=$reg_no");
If return value <= 0 then execute insert query

Answer (score 0):

In your table `reg_no` is `primary key` . You are trying to add to registration table with a duplicate entry for registration number. make the `reg_no` field as `auto_increment` and leave the `reg_no` on `insert`.
New query will look like

```
INSERT INTO patient_registration(patient_main_type_id,   patient_type_id,initial_id,first_name,middle_name,last_name,fth_mth_name,religion_id,date_of_birth,caste_id,address,pin,email,id_proof,phone_office,    phone_residence,mobile_no,name_of_kin,relationship,entry_date,entry_time,patient_photo,payment_mode)
                VALUES('$pmc','$pc','$initial_id','$first_name','$middle_name','$last_name','$fh','$religion_id','$dob','$caste_id','$address','$pin','$email','$id_proof','$phone_office','$phone_resi','$mobile_no','$name_of_kin','','','$relation','$photo','$pmode')";
```

Comment: reg_no is not primary key